# Short-cut when using SN75441 h-bridge (with an Arduino)

Tags: arduino, motor

I'm trying to control 6 bi-directional motors using an Arduino to feed an SN75441.

In order to minimise the number of wires between the two I'd like to tie the Motor Enable pins (1 & 9) to Vcc1 (c. 5v) and use Lo-Lo (or Hi-Hi) on the Motor Logic pins to disable the motor.

My concern is that the Enable pins must be there for a reason.

Is there any reason (other than dodgy Arduino code - I haven't programmed since the early Eighties!) why I shouldn't do this?

---

Funnily enough I woke up this morning pondering the problem and also came up with the idea of tying all the Enable pins together! I hadn't noticed the current draw implications in the datasheet, I'll go back for another look.

Comment: Look at the data sheet - it's possible the current consumed is lower when the enable is disabled.  However, you could gang all of the enables together.  Or perhaps it doesn't make a large difference or doesn't matter in your application.

Comment: You should answer your own question only if you came up with the solution, otherwise use the edit or comment your own question. Also, I noticed that you are using a different user name, perhaps a not-registered account.

Comment: @clabacchio - sorry - got tangled up with the protocol as well as the log-in on my mobile phone! I'm sure I'll settle in soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

Low-Low and High-High isn't a disabled or turned off motor. There are other implications to using those modes, and it is something you may have to consider depending on the kind (size, really) of motors you are using and the kind of movement you want to achieve.

Generally, when you are using a DC motor driven by a H-bridge, the High-High or Low-Low state is referred to as the `braking` state, as opposed to the disable(hiZ)-disable(hiZ) state, referred to as the `coast` state.

In the `braking` state, the motor is forced to be in a stopped condition. Any movement in the motor coming from any secondary factors will act against the motor driver, giving rise to heavy back EMF which can, both in principle and practice, cause damage to your driver circuit if you don't have the necessary back-EMF protection diodes in place. Even if you do have those diodes, with relatively larger motors, the back EMF can be enough to mess up your power rails, so your ADC measurements and so on, if you have any, are liable to get pushed around a bit if the supplies aren't sufficiently isolated.

When I say movement coming from secondary factors, they are usually one of the following :

- Rotor inertia. When you power down a motor, it takes a while to actually stop. This is both because the current takes a while to die down, but more practically, it takes a while for whatever the motor is attached to to stop moving. If you go from full speed to brake in one instant, instead of letting the system decay by friction or what have you, the rotor is forced to decelerate much faster, using the back-EMF protection diodes as a route for the relatively large current spike necessary to allow the rotor to rotate even for the very short time necessary for the sudden deceleration.
- Any external torques on the motor can cause additional movement. As long as the motor is allowed to coast, this is marginally safer since it's the back EMF diodes that take the load, and the voltages aren't forced by the driver. In the braking condition, the motor driver needs to exert itself to force the motor to not move. This could be desirable or not, depending on whatever it is you want to do.

I tend to not use the braking state for most applications. When driving DC motors, I usually find it easier to use two signals :

1. Enable
2. Direction

Enable goes to the enable pin of the motor.
The two motor driver inputs, say inA and inB, get (Direction) and (~Direction) respectively using an inverter. A single transistor and resistor is sufficient to build a cheap inverter, and the CMOS ICs for Hex Inverters aren't expensive either.

If you also need speed control, the PWM signal goes to Enable instead of Direction, to avoid sudden enforced changes in the motor's speed setting (current magnitude / direction).

Of course, if an application really requires me to brake, then inA and inB will need their own pins.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn754410.pdf), the enable pin turns the output to high impedance (as opposed to driving high or low) so it could be used to allow the motor to "freewheel". See the logic table on the first page.

Other than that, if you don't need the pins to be high impedance at any point, then I suppose tying the enable pins to Vcc is fine. Also, as Chris mentions, current consumption is slightly lower with enable low (see page 4)